# Perl regex one line file

Tags: regex, file, perl

I'm using cat to get content of the file, and then I use regex to get what I want. When I change order of if's in example i put PASSWORD as a second one, IP will be empty.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $param = $ARGV[0];

my $IP;
my $PASSWORD;
my $MODEM;
my @cat = `cat file`;

 foreach my $line (@cat){
    if ($line =~ /$param/){
        if ($line =~ /MODEM:(\w+)/g){ $MODEM = $1; }
        if ($line =~ /IP:((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/g){ $IP = $1; }
        if ($line =~ /PASSWORD:(.+)/g){ $PASSWORD = $1; }

        print $MODEM;
        print $IP;
        print $PASSWORD;

        }
}
```

The content of a file (data is changed to fake values) :

```
MODEM:SOMETHING ID:1000018 MAC:606060606060  ID2:123499  IP:1.1.1.1  PASSWORD:pass123
```

Expected result is:

```
SOMETHING1.1.1.1pass123
```

But when I change the line of code to this:

```perl
if ($line =~ /MODEM:(\w+)/g){ $MODEM = $1; }
if ($line =~ /PASSWORD:(.+)/g){ $PASSWORD = $1; }
if ($line =~ /IP:((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/g){ $IP = $1; }
```

the result is :

```
SOMETHINGpass123
```

i.e. the IP is empty. Can someone explain me why this is happening?

Comment: I don't know Perl regex limitations, but you might want to take a look at this Regex101 demo: [link](https://regex101.com/r/X4ww0H/1)

Comment: Don't use `if (/.../g)`; it makes no sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe not the answer you were looking for, but IMHO for your structured data a simpler approach than regex is possible:

- split at white space to access the fields
- each field is of the form `<KEY>:<VALUE`, i.e. can be converted to a hash

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my %fields = map { split(/:/) } split(' ');

    print "$fields{MODEM} $fields{IP} $fields{PASSWORD}\n"
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
MODEM:SOMETHING ID:1000018 MAC:606060606060  ID2:123499  IP:1.1.1.1  PASSWORD:pass123
```

Another alternative would be

```perl
my %fields = /(\S+):(\S+)/g;
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
SOMETHING 1.1.1.1 pass123
```

Answer (score 7):

*Edit: you probably don't really want to use 3 complicated regex to parse your file. See [Stefan Becker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55335160/4990392) for a better way.*

You need to remove the `/g` modifier.

Successive matches against the same string with the `/g` start from the end of the previous match. Have a look at the relevant paragraph in [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Global-matching).
In your file, `MODEM` comes first, then `IP`, then `PASSWORD`. Which means that after matching `/PASSWORD:(.+)/g`, you can't match `/IP/g` which comes before in your string.

---

`/g` modifier is mostly useful when you want to do something like

```
while ($string =~ /.../g) { ... }
```

Or of course, in list context, to get all the matches:

```
 @matches = $string =~ /.../g
```

In your case, you just want to get different matches one by one, so no need for `/g` modifier.

Comment: I'd suggest just selecting the whole lot into a hash as an alternative approach. `my %lookup = `cat file` =~ m/(\w+):(\S+)/g;` which will pull out key-values.

Comment: @Sobrique indeed, it sounds more reasonable